# Numpy eigenvectors

Tags: numpy

I am trying to use the `numpy`'s `linalg.eig()` function to get eigenvectors and eigenvalues.

```
import numpy as np
M = np.array([[168.04570515, 1.38100609, -48.60662242],
              [1.38100609, 16.49647382, 9.18370965], 
              [-48.60662242, 9.18370965, 38.37842496]])
eigenvalue, eigenvector = np.linalg.eig(M)

>>>eigenvalue
array([184.25812834,  28.91371368,   9.74876191])

>>>eigenvector
array([[-0.94849917, -0.26039343, -0.18040119],
   [ 0.0095255 , -0.59267178,  0.80538775],
   [ 0.31663637, -0.7621912 , -0.56462906]])
```

However, when I input the same `M` values into WolframAlpha, I get the following:
[image]

Why do I get different eigenvectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are actually getting the same eigenvectors. It's just that Wolfram Alpha scales the eigenvectors so the last element is 1 (if you recall, eigenvectors are scale invariant). Let's look at the first column of your result. If you run,

```
np.array([-0.94849917, 0.0095255, 0.31663637])/0.31663637
```

You will get

```
array([-2.99554713,  0.0300834 ,  1.        ])
```

Which if you notice is what Wolfram Alpha reports. You can check the other two as well.